# querySelectorAll('lightning-input') shows empty

Tags: lightning-web-components

From what i understand if i use querySelectorAll('lightning-input') then all of the 'lightning-input' that have been filled out in the lwc should display in that console.log. But console.log shows nothing.

the javascript that is being called on:

```
  someFunction() {
        let inputs = this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input');
        console.log(' show inputs ' + JSON.stringify(inputs));
```

function is being called and those lightning-inputs are filled out but the log shows blank

The HTML:

```
<template>
<c-wizard header="Create Ticket Flow" variant="path" current-step="step-1" oncomplete={navigateToCase}>
    <c-wizard-step label="Create " name="step-1" before-change={someFunction}>
        <lightning-input label="Ticket Subject" data-field-name="Subject" required></lightning-input>
        <lightning-input label="Ticket Description" data-field-name="Description"></lightning-input>
    </c-wizard-step>
    <c-wizard-step label="Enter Ticket Details" name="step-2">
        <c-file-upload upload-record-id={ticketId}></c-file-upload>
    </c-wizard-step>
</c-wizard>
```

and here is the console.log()

```
show inputs "[]"
```

Comment: where is `someFunction`?  in `wizard` or `wizardStep`?

Comment: Also, are you sure all the markup has rendered? If you are running this in `connectedCallback()` it won't find any inputs. You would need to run in or after `renderedCallback()` has been invoked.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare the inputs as an array first, like this

```
someFunction(){
    let inputs = [];
    this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input').forEach(input => {
        inputs.push(input.value);
    })
    console.log("I am the lightning input", inputs);
}
```

So from each of the lightning-input, I am extracting it's value and adding to the array, if there are 2 lighting-input and I only entered value for 1. This will also print an array of 2, one with the value I entered and another one with ''.

If you want to print the label and the value, for example:
[{"Name":"Felix"}, {"Age":"22"}], where it print's the label of the lightning-input with it's corresponding value.

You can do it this way,

```
someFunction(){
    let inputs = [];
    this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input').forEach(input => {
            let o = {};
            o[input.label] = input.value;
            inputs.push(o);
        })
    console.log("this is the lightning input", JSON.stringify(inputs));
 }
```

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Problem is [input.label] gives the label instead of the field name. I had to use o[field.dataset.field] instead. Then using let o = {}; creates this structure {"apiName":"Case","fields":[{"Subject":"test"},{"Description":"test description"},{"RecordTypeId":"0127i000003TbOzAAK"}]} the problem with that is createRecord can't accept that kind of structure. These {} can't be there. has to be more like {"apiName":"Case","fields":["Subject":"test","Description":"Test description","RecordTypeId":"0127i000003TbOzAAK"]}